# Python Flask - Returning values that has the same variable

Tags: python, flask

So I have a problem here with my code, I am trying to return values to my HTML from python. Now I am using an API with over 190 products, and they all get stored in variables such as itemName, buyPrice, sellPrice etc.

If I write in my HTML for example:

## {{ itemName }}

and I write this multiple times, and returning using:
return ("index.html", itemName=itemName)

it will of course return the same name over and over again, now I want it to return the first name, then the second name, then the third name and so on, same for buy and sell price.

The names are in an array called "product", and the prices etc are in an API which I use request.get(...) on. My code is down below

```
import requests
import time
import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


product = [
    "BROWN_MUSHROOM",
    "INK_SACK:3",  # cocao beans
    "INK_SACK:4",  # lapis lazuli
    "TARANTULA_WEB",
    "CARROT_ITEM",
    "ENCHANTED_POTATO",
    "ENCHANTED_SLIME_BALL",
    "ENCHANTED_GOLDEN_CARROT",
    "ENCHANTED_RED_MUSHROOM",
    "ENCHANTED_RABBIT_HIDE",
    "ENCHANTED_BIRCH_LOG",
    "ENCHANTED_GUNPOWDER",
    "ENCHANTED_MELON",
    "ENCHANTED_SUGAR",
    "CACTUS",
    "ENCHANTED_BLAZE_ROD",
    "ENCHANTED_CAKE",
    "PUMPKIN",
    "ENCHANTED_BROWN_MUSHROOM",
    "WHEAT",
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_SALMON",
    "ENCHANTED_GLISTERING_MELON",
    "PRISMARINE_SHARD",
    "PROTECTOR_FRAGMENT",
    "ENCHANTED_EMERALD",
    "ENCHANTED_SPIDER_EYE",
    "RED_MUSHROOM",
    "MUTTON",
    "ENCHANTED_MELON_BLOCK",
    "DIAMOND",
    "WISE_FRAGMENT",
    "COBBLESTONE",
    "SPIDER_EYE",
    "RAW_FISH",
    "ENCHANTED_PUFFERFISH",
    "POTATO_ITEM",
    "ENCHANTED_HUGE_MUSHROOM_1",  # enchanted brown mushroom block
    "ENCHANTED_COBBLESTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_HUGE_MUSHROOM_2",  # enchanted red mushroom block
    "PORK",
    "PRISMARINE_CRYSTALS",
    "ICE",
    "HUGE_MUSHROOM_1",  # brown mushroom block
    "HUGE_MUSHROOM_2",  # red mushroom block
    "LOG_2:1",  # dark oak
    "ENCHANTED_SNOW_BLOCK",
    "GOLDEN_TOOTH",
    "STRING",
    "RABBIT_FOOT",
    "REDSTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_CACTUS_GREEN",
    "ENCHANTED_CARROT_STICK",
    "ENCHANTED_LAPIS_LAZULI_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKIE",
    "ENCHANTED_ENDSTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_SAND",
    "ENCHANTED_STRING",
    "STRONG_FRAGMENT",
    "SLIME_BALL",
    "ENCHANTED_ACACIA_LOG",
    "SNOW_BALL",
    "ENCHANTED_EGG",
    "SAND",
    "RAW_CHICKEN",
    "ENCHANTED_LAPIS_LAZULI",
    "ENCHANTED_GHAST_TEAR",
    "ENCHANTED_COCOA",
    "SEEDS",
    "ENCHANTED_LEATHER",
    "ENCHANTED_SPONGE",
    "HAY_BLOCK",
    "FLINT",
    "INK_SACK",
    "WOLF_TOOTH",
    "ENCHANTED_SPRUCE_LOG",
    "ENCHANTED_ROTTEN_FLESH",
    "ENCHANTED_GRILLED_PORK",
    "ENCHANTED_NETHER_STALK",
    "ENCHANTED_REDSTONE_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_QUARTZ_BLOCK",
    "GREEN_CANDY",
    "ENCHANTED_REDSTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_REDSTONE_LAMP",
    "GRAVEL",
    "MELON",
    "ENCHANTED_LAVA_BUCKET",
    "ENCHANTED_PACKED_ICE",
    "RAW_FISH:3",  # pufferfish
    "ENCHANTED_PRISMARINE_SHARD",
    "ENCHANTED_CARROT_STICK",
    "ENCHANTED_IRON_BLOCK",
    "BONE",
    "RAW_FISH:2",  # clownfish
    "RAW_FISH:1",  # raw salmon
    "REVENANT_FLESH",
    "ENCHANTED_PORK",
    "ENCHANTED_GLOWSTONE",
    "FEATHER",
    "NETHERRACK",
    "SPONGE",
    "BLAZE_ROD",
    "ENCHANTED_DARK_OAK_LOG",
    "YOUNG_FRAGMENT",
    "ENCHANTED_CLOWNFISH",
    "ENCHANTED_GOLD",
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_CHICKEN",
    "ENCHANTED_WATER_LILY",
    "LOG:1",  # spruce
    "CATALYST",
    "LOG:3",  # jungle
    "LOG:2",  # birch
    "ENCHANTED_GLOWSTONE_DUST",
    "ENCHANTED_INK_SACK",
    "ENCHANTED_CACTUS",
    "ENCHANTED_SUGAR_CANE",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKED_SALMON",
    "ENCHANTED_SEEDS",
    "LOG",  # oak
    "GHAST_TEAR",
    "ENCHANTED_ENDER_PEARL",
    "UNSTABLE_FRAGMENT",
    "PURPLE_CANDY",
    "ENCHANTED_FERMENTED_SPIDER_EYE",
    "ENCHANTED_GOLD_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_JUNGLE_LOG",
    "ENCHANTED_FLINT",
    "IRON_INGOT",
    "ENCHANTED_EMERALD_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_CLAY_BALL",
    "GLOWSTONE_DUST",
    "GOLD_INGOT",
    "REVENANT_VISCERA",
    "TARANTULA_SILK",
    "ENCHANTED_MUTTON",
    "SUPER_EGG",
    "SUPER_COMPACTOR_3000",
    "ENCHANTED_IRON",
    "STOCK_OF_STONKS",
    "ENCHANTED_HAY_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_BONE",
    "ENCHANTED_PAPER",
    "ENCHANTED_DIAMOND_BLOCK",
    "SUPERIOR_FRAGMENT",
    "EMERALD",
    "ENCHANTED_RABBIT_FOOT",
    "ENCHANTED_ICE",
    "HOT_POTATO_BOOK",
    "CLAY_BALL",
    "OLD_FRAGMENT",
    "GREEN_GIFT",
    "PACKED_ICE",
    "WATER_LILY",  # lily pad
    "LOG_2",  # acacia
    "HAMSTER_WHEEL",
    "ENCHANTED_OBSIDIAN",
    "ENCHANTED_COAL",
    "ENCHANTED_QUARTZ",
    "COAL",
    "ENDER_PEARL",
    "ENCHANTED_COAL_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_PRISMARINE_CRYSTALS",
    "ENCHANTED_WET_SPONGE",
    "ENDER_STONE",  # end stone
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_FISH",
    "QUARTZ",
    "FOUL_FLESH",
    "RAW_BEEF",
    "ENCHANTED_EYE_OF_ENDER",
    "SUGAR_CANE",
    "MAGMA_CREAM",
    "RED_GIFT",
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_BEEF",
    "ENCHANTED_SLIME_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_FEATHER",
    "ENCHANTED_OAK_LOG",
    "RABBIT_HIDE",
    "WHITE_GIFT",
    "RABBIT",
    "NETHER_STALK",
    "SULPHUR",
    "ENCHANTED_CARROT",
    "ENCHANTED_PUMPKIN",
    "ROTTEN_FLESH",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKED_FISH",
    "OBSIDIAN",
    "ENCHANTED_MAGMA_CREAM",
    "ENCHANTED_FIREWORK_ROCKET",
    "LEATHER",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKED_MUTTON",
    "ENCHANTED_RABBIT",
    "ENCHANTED_BREAD",
    "ENCHANTED_CHARCOAL",
    "ENCHANTED_BLAZE_POWDER",
    "SUMMONING_EYE",
    "SNOW_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_BAKED_POTATO",
    "COMPACTOR",
    "ENCHANTED_DIAMOND"
]

for x in product:
    f = requests.get(
        "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar/product?key=[key supposed to be secret]&productId=" + x).json()

    # Item Name
    itemName = f["product_info"]["product_id"]
    # TimeStamp
    timestamp = f["product_info"]["week_historic"][0]["timestamp"]

    unixTimestamp = timestamp / 1000.0

    # Buy Price
    buyPrice = f["product_info"]["buy_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"]
    # Buy Amount
    buyAmount = f["product_info"]["buy_summary"][0]["amount"]
    # Buy Orders
    buyOrders = f["product_info"]["buy_summary"][0]["orders"]

    # Sell Price
    sellPrice = f["product_info"]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"]
    # Sell Amount
    sellAmount = f["product_info"]["sell_summary"][0]["amount"]
    # Sell Orders
    sellOrders = f["product_info"]["sell_summary"][0]["orders"]

    # Week History
    # Buys
    buys = f["product_info"]["week_historic"][0]["buys"]
    # Buy Volume
    buyVolume = f["product_info"]["week_historic"][0]["buyVolume"]
    # Sells
    sells = f["product_info"]["week_historic"][0]["sells"]
    # Sell Volume
    sellVolume = f["product_info"]["week_historic"][0]["sellVolume"]

    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html", itemName=itemName)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You have to do it in your index.html. Can you show html file?

Comment: I don't have the HTML the same as it was before, tried to do changes but no luck, this is how it looked inside of the body tags. https://pastebin.com/eufThtLW (easier to read there) I use Jinja if that helps by the way.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the requirements you need, the loop should be in the html file.
Here is the [documentation from Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/)

Here is an example of what you could do, based in your currrent configuration for  `@app.route("/")`

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", product=product)
```

Just changed the template variable to be `product`.
After that change you just have to iterate over that in your html file.
Here it is a minimal example with the changes you need to do.

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% for item in product %}
     <h1>{{ item }}</h1>
     {% endfor %}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

To use the values from api, you have to create a new list, and pass it to the template... Just iterate over and put the data in the new list. After that pass new list to the view.

```
full_list = list()
for x in product:
    row = list()
    row.append(x)
    f = requests.get(
    "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar/product?key=[key supposed to be secret]&productId=" + x).json()

    # Item Name
    itemName = f["product_info"]["product_id"]
    row.append(itemName)
    # TimeStamp
    timestamp = f["product_info"]["week_historic"][0]["timestamp"]
    row.append(timestamp)
    unixTimestamp = timestamp / 1000.0

    # Buy Price
    buyPrice = f["product_info"]["buy_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"]
    row.append(buyPrice)
    # Buy Amount
    buyAmount = f["product_info"]["buy_summary"][0]["amount"]
    row.append(buyAmount)
    #and so on with every information you need in html.
    #...
    full_list.append(row)
```

Now is only change your  `@app.route("/")` and `index.html` with your new template variable name:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", full_list=full_list)
```

Comment: will this also work for the - buyPrice, sellPrice etc? I get these values from the API, when I tried to launch the code it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past by returning the responses to a list and then passing the list to the view function

```
itemNameList = []

for x in product:
    itemName = f["product_info"]["product_id"]
    itemNameList = itemNameList.append(itemName)
```

Comment: Do you mean to store all the values into a new array, maybe even a JSON file then exporting the data from JSON to my html?

Comment: Yes save it into a new array and I would iterate using jinja in the HTML. As another answer has suggested here you could also just pass the product array to the view function. It depends a little on how your HTML is built and whether you need to separate out the individual properties (like itemNames) in your Product and run separate loops.